# Prove $f^{-1}[⋂_iB_i]=⋂_if^{−1}[B_i]$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$$f : X \to Y , A_i \subseteq Y$$ for all $$i \in I$$
Please prove $$f^{-1}\left(⋂_iA_i\right)=⋂_if^{−1}(A_i) $$

What I did was let $$x \in \bigcap_i f^{-1}(A_i)$$
There exists $$ i \in I, x \in f^{-1}(B_j) $$
Is the last statement correct, I understand that for the union symbol, it would be correct. Is it the same for the intercept?

Comment: In first line is $A_i$, in third $B_i$. And If it's only typo, then where they should be - in domain?

Comment: You're getting lots of downvotes because you haven't provided your own attempts. Please edit your question with what you've done, or if you can't start it at all at the very least some thoughts about the question and what you understand about it.

Comment: Please see edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $x\in f^{-1}(\bigcap_{i\in I}A_i)$. Then $f(x)\in \bigcap_{i\in I}A_i$, and so $f(x)\in A_i$ for all $i\in I$. Hence, by taking the inverse image, $x\in f^{-1}(A_i)$ for all $i\in I$. Therefore $x\in \bigcap_{i\in I}f^{-1}(A_i)$. This means $ f^{-1}(\bigcap_{i\in I}A_i)\subset \bigcap_{i\in I}f^{-1}(A_i)$.

Conversely, take $x\in \bigcap_{i\in I}f^{-1}(A_i)$, then $x\in f^{-1}(A_i)$ for all $i\in I$. Therefore $f(x)\in A_i$ for all $i\in I$. Then $f(x)\in\bigcap_{i\in I}A_i$ and therefore $x\in f^{-1}(\bigcap_{i\in I}A_i)$. This means that $\bigcap_{i\in I}f^{-1}(A_i)\subset f^{-1}(\bigcap_{i\in I}A_i)$.

Now since $ f^{-1}(\bigcap_{i\in I}A_i)\subset \bigcap_{i\in I}f^{-1}(A_i)$ and $\bigcap_{i\in I}f^{-1}(A_i)\subset f^{-1}(\bigcap_{i\in I}A_i)$ then we must have $f^{-1}(\bigcap_{i\in I}A_i) = f^{-1}(\bigcap_{i\in I}A_i)$ as required.

Answer (score 1):

$$x \in f^{-1}\left(\bigcap_i A_i\right) \Leftrightarrow f(x) \in \bigcap_i A_i\Leftrightarrow \forall i, f(x) \in A_i \Leftrightarrow \forall i, x \in f^{-1}(A_i)\Leftrightarrow x \in \bigcap_i f^{-1}(A_i)$$